# Automatic capitalisation and typesetting correction for TeX, LaTeX and FrieNds.

Tags: feature-request, design

It would be great for `latex, tex and context` and similar words be automatically converted to `LaTeX, TeX and ConTeXt` preferably even with proper baselines.

Comment: No, sometimes one really means the `latex` command as opposed to the `LaTeX` system.

Comment: How about having `\latex` automatically converted to `LaTeX`

Comment: possible duplicate of [We need Tex markup...](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7/we-need-tex-markup)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not when it refers to a command name!

Comment: `latex` = command/engine, LaTeX = syntax/language

Comment: But relying on people to know that they should put command names in backticks is dangerous.  Frankly, I get fed up with doing it all the time and feel that it often breaks up the display unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair this is a duplicate of "we need latex processing engine / embedder" on the website. Since any such solution would be able to handle \latex and friends ;-)

Comment: Not really because the "we need latex processing" really means "we need latex _maths_ processing" which wouldn't (necessarily) include \latex etc.  As I don't agree that we need _either_ of these, then I'm not overly bothered!

Comment: @Andrew Stacey

Insightful and funny comment =)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't mean that to read snarkily.  All I meant was to register that I disagree that this is a duplicate.

Comment: If we just wanted maths, mathjax would do quite nicely. As it is, if we wanted anything, we'd want something that let us demo our minimal [non-]working examples ...